# not able to fetch huge amonut of data in json php

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
    <?php 
i am using limit suppose 2000 it is fetch data but without using limit it is not fetching data   
    $db=new PDO('mysql:dbname="";host=;','','',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

    $str_id=$_POST['Store_Id'];    
    $row=$db->prepare("select  Store_Id from store where Store_Id='$str_id'");  
    $row->execute();//execute the query
     header("content-type:application/json");  
    $json_data=array();//create the array  
    foreach($row as $rec)//foreacc loop  
    {      
    $Store_id=$rec['Store_Id']; 



    array_push($json_data,$json_array);   
    } 
     header("content-type:application/json"); 



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------retail_str_po_detail_hold-----------------------------------------------------------------//                     

    $row49=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM storeprod where S_Flag='0' and Store_Id='$Store_id'");    
    $row49->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $row49->execute();//execute the query  
    $json_data49=array();//create the array 

    $json_arr=array();
    while($record49=$row49->fetch())
    {       
    foreach($record49 as $rec49)//foreacc loop  
    {    
    $json_array49['field']=$rec49;  
    $array_push($json_data49,$json_array49);
    }
    }
```

i am using limit suppose 2000 it is fetch data but without using limit it is not fetching data
        $result['Retail_store_prod_com'] =$json_data49; 
        echo json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $json_arr = json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        //-----------------------------------------------------sucessresponse--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    ?>
```

Comment: can anyone can provide code to help me out i am not able to insert it

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i am counting columns from mysql and trying to inserting it into mysql but it is not working

Comment: can anyone help me out by providing a code

Comment: can you Share your code

Comment: ok just sharing my code

Comment: plze had a look i had just shared my code

Comment: help me with this code i am stuck it is not fetching data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cnt = 0;
$rows = array('John',123, 'Lloyds Office','Jane',124, 'Lloyds Office','Billy',125, 'London Office','Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
$insertQry = "insert into MyTable ( Name,     Id,   Location)        values ";
foreach($rows as $row) {
  if($cnt == 3) {
     $insertQry = rtrim($insertQry ,", ");
     $insertQry .= "), ";
  }
  if($cnt > 2) {
    $cnt = 0;
  }
  if($cnt == 0) {
     $insertQry .= "(";
  } 

  $insertQry .= $row.", ";
  $cnt++;
}
$insertQry = rtrim($insertQry ,", ");
$insertQry .= ");";
```

Output:

```
insert into MyTable ( Name, Id, Location) values (John, 123, Lloyds Office), (Jane, 124, Lloyds Office), (Billy, 125, London Office), (Miranda, 126, Bristol Office);
```

Comment: hey thks for you help but how to to with 15 values i had just shared my code

Comment: hey thanks for your help supoose if there are 15 columns then how to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Try `array_chunk` i hope its helps to you

```
<?php

$row= array('John',123, 'Lloyds Office','Jane',124, 'Lloyds Office','Billy',125, 'London Office','Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
$arraychuk = array_chunk($row, 3);


for($i=0;$i<count($arraychuk);$i++){

    echo "<pre>".print_r($arraychuk[$i]);

    insert into MyTable ( Name,     Id,   Location)
             values ($arraychuk[$i][0],   $arraychuk[$i][1], $arraychuk[$i][2]));


}
```

While using `array_chunk` you will get something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Jane
    [1] => 124
    [2] => Lloyds Office
)
Array
(
    [0] => Billy
    [1] => 125
    [2] => London Office
)
Array
(
    [0] => Miranda
    [1] => 126
    [2] => Bristol Office
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i dont want to pass manually a columns number neither a column names

Comment: where u need to pass manually ? you check these lines `insert into MyTable ( Name,     Id,   Location)    values ($arraychuk[$i][0],   $arraychuk[$i][1], $arraychuk[$i][2]));` will solve ur question

Comment: it will done dynamically u dont need to give anything. i thnk u dont understand my code

Comment: please update ur question so that we will check where u are going wrong

Comment: first of all it is not inserting data and he is showing first only 15 data

Comment: overall only first 15 data is in action after loop

Comment: just echo the insert query and past the result here

Comment: Array ( [0] => 146615279 [1] => 8 [2] => Vendor 8 [3] => NULL [4] => NULL [5] => NULL [6] => SriLanka [7] => NULL [8] => NULL [9] => NULL [10] => arunmehra991@gmail.com [11] => N [12] => N [13] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [14] => 0 )

Comment: this is the result

Comment: pls print the insert query

Comment: insert into store_vendor1 VALUES (" insert into INSERT INTO retail_store vendor1(Store_Id, Vend_Id, Vend_Nm, Vend_cntct_Nm, Add_1, City, Ctr_Desc, Zip, Tele, Mobile, Email,Vend_Inv, Active) values ($arraychuk[$i][0],   $arraychuk[$i][1], $arraychuk[$i][2],$arraychuk[$i][3],$arraychuk[$i][4],$arraychuk[$i][5],$arraychuk[$i][6],$arraychuk[$i][7],$arraychuk[$i][8],$arraychuk[$i][9],$arraychuk[$i][10],$arraychuk[$i][11],$arraychuk[$i][12],$arraychuk[$i][13],$arraychuk[$i][14],$arraychuk[$i][15])")

Comment: i had printed insert query only

Comment: 1

1falseArray
(
    [0] => 1446615279
    [1] => 8
    [2] => Vendor 8
    [3] => NULL
    [4] => NULL
    [5] => NULL
    [6] => SriLanka
    [7] => NULL
    [8] => NULL
    [9] => NULL
    [10] => arunmehra991@gmail.com
    [11] => N
    [12] => N
    [13] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [14] => 0
)

1

1false

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$row= array('John',123, 'Lloyds Office','Jane',124, 'Lloyds Office','Billy',125, 'London Office','Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
$arraychuk = array_chunk($row, 3);

foreach ($arraychuk as $array_num => $array) {
  echo "Array $array_num:\n";
 }


?>
```

//you can easily chunk like which will break into a perfect array